# Is there a mathematical notation that represents "up until" or "once reached"?

Tags: notation, biology

I am a biologist and I need some math help. I am writing a paper about how population density affects life-history traits of a snail. I want to list descriptive statistics of several life-history traits but I only need help with growth rate. We measure growth rate by measuring the shell length of each snail once a week using calipers and the way we calculate growth rate is `((Size at sexual maturity- initial size in the experiment)/ days until size at sexual maturity was reached)`. The reason we use "size at sexual maturity" in this equation is because the growth of this organism slows down once it reaches sexual maturity, which is at 3 millimeters.

I want to list descriptive statistics of growth rate so I need to make sure the values have a unit of measurement. However, what I have right now is `median: ## (m per day up until sexual maturity at 3mm)` I would have to write this measurement unit multiple times and I want to short-hand it. I was thinking of `mm/d up until 3 mm` but I think the "up until" part is still too many words. Do you all have any notations for "up until" or "once reach"? I was considering `mm/d ≥ 3mm` but I feel that measurement unit reads as `millimeters per day greater than or equal to 3 millimeters` and that's not what I am trying to convey.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The unit of measurement is just meters per day. The "up until" information is part of the experiment procedure, not part of the units.

Comment: This is not a mathematics question, it seems to be more of a question in the terminology of statistics. Perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com would be a good place to ask? Or even just https://biology.stackexchange.com where folks might have though about such terminology issues?